# Suggestions for optimization of code to pass TLE on SPOJ

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, data-structures

I'm trying to solve a problem which is something like this:

I'm given n numbers (1<=n<=10^5).I have to write the sum of all numbers on its left which are smaller than the current number and repeat the process for all n numbers.Then I have to find the sum of all previously obtained sum's.(Each number N,0<=N<=10^6).

For example,

```
1 5 3 6 4
less1 less5 less3 less6 less4
 (0) + (1) + (1)+(1+5+3)+(1+3)
  0  +  1  +  1  +  9  +  4
= 15
```

A trivial solution for this problem will be to run two loops and for each of the given number find sum of all the numbers less than that number and finally give the sum of those sum's as output.The time complexity is O(n^2).

I think a better O(nlogn) solution for this problem using Binary Indexed Tree(Fenwick Tree).
For each number I'll add each of the number in a global array a and perform two obvious operations of BIT.I think the time complexity of this algorithm is O(nlogn) which if true is obviously better than the previous O(n^2).

I have implemented the code in C++.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>

using namespace std;

#define max 1000001

long int a[max];

void add(long int v,int idx){
while(idx<max){
    a[idx] += v;
    idx += (idx & -idx);
}
}

long int sum(int idx){
long int s=0;
while(idx>0){
    s += a[idx];
    idx -= (idx & -idx);
}
return s;
 }

 int main()
 {
int t;
scanf("%d",&t);
for(int w=0;w<t;w++){
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(int i=0;i<max;i++)
        a[i]=0;

    int arr[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);

    long long res=0;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(arr[i]!=0){
           add(arr[i],arr[i]);
           res += (sum(arr[i]-1));
                     }  
    }

    printf("%lld\n",res);
}

return 0;
}
```

I have two questions:

First, am I doing it correct? / Is my logic correct?

Second, if I'm right about the time complexity to be O(nlogn) then why does it run slow? Can you help me with any further optimizations?

Got Accepted with 1.41 seconds.At same time I have updated my finally accepted code.Any suggestion for optimization ?

Based on the comments I tried my own function for faster I/O but still it's not going my way.This is my function for fast I/O :

```
 inline int read(){
char c=getchar_unlocked();
int n=0;
while(!(c>='0' && c<='9'))
    c=getchar_unlocked();

while(c>='0' && c<='9'){
    n=n*10 + (c-'0');
    c=getchar_unlocked();   
}
return n;
 }
```

This is the link to the problem :

http://www.spoj.pl/problems/DCEPC206/

If there is anyone who is abled to solve it,please let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide an example? For example, what is the expected output for `5 2 3 9 6 4`?

Comment: @IVlad: I have edited teh question and gave an example for it.BTW for your input my code gives 27.

Comment: It's still unclear. Can you give step-by-step example?

Comment: I would guess `0+0+2+9+10+6=27`.  I added a step by step to his existing sample

Comment: For the input 5 2 3 9 6 4 the answer will be 27 (0+0+2+10+10+5).I hope it's clear now.

Comment: @IVlad - The partial sums are 0, 0, 2, 10, 10, 5, which sum to 27.

Comment: How slow is slow? Your code seems correct and fast.

Comment: @IVlad : I have tested my code for t cases(t<=10).For each test case I can have n numbers (1<=n<=10^5) where each number N ( 0<=N<=10^6).The code fails to run in a bound of 3 seconds.

Comment: @dark_shadow, are you sure, you not spend all the time in IO? I've tried replacing input with `rand() % (max - 1)) + 1` and set `n = 100001;` and even with `-O0` I got `0.2s`

Comment: @IVlad : I'm using printf() and scanf() for that purpose.I think it's best in a C++ code rather than using cin and cout.Are you sure it's taking 0.2 seconds because I run it on SPOJ machine and it's taking more than 3 seconds.

Comment: @dark_shadow, heh, and even I make correct range for `rand` it works in 0.6 with optimization desibled

Comment: @dark_shadow, also note, that just printing all `arr` generated to _file_, (that is faster, then console), takes `2.7s`

Comment: You should try using fread. It's much faster than scanf.

Comment: Whatever you use to do I/O, it'll still be the slowest component of this little algorithm. Do your I/O outside the code you're measuring the time of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your approach is a good one.  I've played around with this a wee bit and haven't come up with anything generally better than what you have.

There are a couple of bugs in your code though.  There are a few places suffering from integer overflow.  You should change to:

```
long long a[max];
```

and

```
long long sum(int idx){
long long s=0;
```

The more apparent bug is that you're summing numbers which are less than *or equal to* the current number.  To fix this issue, you could add a second global array for tracking the count of each value:

```
int b[max];
...
...
    for(int i=0;i<max;i++)
        a[i]=b[i]=0;
    ...
    ...
        res += (sum(idx)-(++b[idx]*val));
```

There may be a more efficient way to fix that bug, but overall it still seems like a fast solution.

Comment: "+1" for finding out a big bug in my program but solution is not quite impressive.A better solution would be to just have res += sum(idx-1) since I have to remove all occurrences of same value which is equal to current value.I tried it.It works fine.There is no need to have an extra array to keep track of frequency of each term.But still my problem is TLE on spoj.Any help with it will be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: OK - I'm not surprised there's a better way to handle the bug :-)  Nice one.  Also, if you take 0 as a valid value for the numbers, your solution hangs in the `add` function since `0 += (0 & -0); == 0`.  It's not clear to me whether 0 is a valid input, but if so, this could be the TLE issue.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach: the problem is similar to counting inversions, except you have to sum the elements responsible for generating inversions. We can solve this using merge sort. Modify the merge function like this:

```
merge(left, middle, right, array)
  temp = new array
  k = 0, i = left, j = middle + 1

  while i <= middle and j <= right
    if array[i] < array[j]
      temp[k++] = array[i]
      // array[i] is also smaller than all array[j+1], ..., array[right]
      globalSum += array[i] * (right - j + 1)
    else
      // same as the classical function
```

Intuitively, I would say a recursive mergesort is slower than a BIT solution, but who knows? Give it a try.

**Edit:** This gets AC:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define max 100001

int n;
long long res = 0;

int temp[max];
int arr[max];
void merge(int left, int m, int right)
{
    int k = 0;
    int i = left, j = m + 1;
    while (i <= m && j <= right)
        if (arr[i] < arr[j])
        {
            temp[k++] = arr[i];
            res += (long long)(right - j + 1) * arr[i++];
        }
        else
            temp[k++] = arr[j++];

    while (j <= right)
        temp[k++] = arr[j++];
    while (i <= m)
        temp[k++] = arr[i++];

    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
        arr[left + i] = temp[i];
}

void sort(int left, int right)
{
    if (left < right)
    {
        int m = left + (right - left) / 2;
        sort(left, m);
        sort(m + 1, right);
        merge(left, m, right);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    for(int w=0;w<t;w++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &n);
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            scanf("%d", &arr[i]);

        res=0;
        sort(0, n - 1);

        printf("%lld\n",res);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have one doubt.Do you really think only slow IO is responsible for slowness of program.I'm saying this because I have submitted other problems on SPOJ as well and even if it's IO oriented problem using a function read() as defined by me in above code should be sufficient to give me an Accepted answer.I have started doubting my way of solving the problem with BIT.Perhaps I should start from scratch and start thinking a fresh new algorithm that's much faster than this one. :(

Comment: I think it's possible. BIT is usually very fast, so I would at least try this before starting from scratch. I can't say for sure though.

Comment: Taking arr[n] out of the loop is not working out for me.I'm still getting TLE.BTW Thanks for giving your precious time for my problem.

Comment: I think your skepticism was correct: I cannot get rid of the TLE error using my suggestion. Back to the drawing board, I guess. I will edit this if I think of something.

Comment: @dark_shadow - I have suggested a different approach, please look over it.

Comment: I don't think it is in any case fater way than my suggested approach.Have you made a program for it and tested it on SPOJ because I'm sure it can't pass 3 seconds TLE.I guess you must check it once on SPOJ itself.

Comment: @dark_shadow - I just implemented and submitted and I got AC in 0.5 seconds. I think the important difference is that my solution is `O(n log n)`, while yours is actually `O(n log N)`. Yours still shouldn't TLE I think, so you might be able to get it to work, although I'm not sure what to suggest. Is a `long int` 64 bits on SPOJ? If not, you should use `long long`. Well, I posted my code. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks IVlad for your help.Finally got AC with my original code after correcting the error as suggested  by Fraser.I'm getting AC in 1.41 sec.I still wonder why is it taking that much time.If your recursive approach can get AC in 0.5s then why the hell is my BIT code(which is generally considered to be a faster one) is taking too much time ? Can you help me to figure out that ? Thanks

Comment: @dark_shadow - like I said, your code is `O(n log N)` and mine is `O(n log n)`, where `n` = number of integers in the input and `N` = max size of each integer in the input. The maximum value of `N` can be 10 times larger than `n`. This might not seem like much because of the `log`, but it adds up quickly with a large `n` and a lot of test cases. Another thing is that you most likely have a larger constant factor: you have two calls to an `O(log N)` function for each of the `n` elements. This increases the number of operations by 2. Also note that you use 10 times as much memory as I do.

Comment: Recursion is not necessarily slow either. I don't do anything more expensive than you do: additions, subtractions, multiplications and assignments. You just have a slightly worse complexity and larger constant factor. Coupled with the fact that the SPOJ judge runs on a rather slow machine, the difference between the two algorithms is very noticeable. If you were to run the two on a modern desktop CPU, I would say the difference would be a lot smaller, if even noticeable.

Comment: Thanks IVlad for the help and suggestions.I'll keep those things in my mind for future problem solving.